# XNA UV Mapping flipping the Texture every second time

Tags: xna, uv-mapping

I am making a tile based game. Recently I moved to drawing tiles as primitives to speed up things and also allow for easier lighting (Vertex Shader).

I then took it a step further and made some calculations to "merge" together tiles into the same primitive to gain even more performance, and to get around UV texture problems I simply did this...

```
if (!top)
{
    //Adds the top vertices
    thisquad.Vertices[0] = new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3(new Vector2(p.X, p.Y), 0), new Vector2(0, 0));
    thisquad.Vertices[1] = new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3(new Vector2(Tile.Size + p.X, p.Y), 0), new Vector2(1, 0));
    top = true;
}
//Extends the bottom vertices
thisquad.Vertices[2] = new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3(new Vector2(p.X, Tile.Size + p.Y), 0), new Vector2(0, currentquadtilecount));
thisquad.Vertices[3] = new VertexPositionTexture(new Vector3(new Vector2(Tile.Size + p.X, Tile.Size + p.Y), 0), new Vector2(1, currentquadtilecount));
currentquadtilecount++;
```

With currentquadtilecount starting at 1, if a tile is floating on its own it will display the texture properly, but for every second tile that merges, the texture is flipped. As shown below...

[image: Example Image]

What am I doing wrong? Is this even the right way to do this??

Twitchy

Comment: And did it speed things up? I always found SpriteBatch to be very efficient when used correctly (probably more than a typical hand rolled version). And by the way you can do *both* vertex/pixel shaders and tile merging quite easily with the SpriteBatch too.

Comment: E.g. For a vertex shader example with SpriteBatch check [this](http://www.david-gouveia.com/scrolling-textures-with-zoom-and-rotation/). There's also a pixel shader version at the end which I left in for future reference. Basically pass the effect to SpriteBatch.Begin(). As for merging tiles together with SpriteBatch, read [this](http://www.david-amador.com/2010/04/making-big-grass-tiles-in-xna/) (although it was written before XNA4 came out). Basically turn on TextureAddressMode.Wrap and use a source rectangle corresponding to the size you want the entire merged area to be.

Comment: Oh yes it did! (I have a key to change between 2D and 3D drawing) With a full screen of tiles, 2D was running at 500fps. while 3D ran at 800-900fps.

Comment: That's really cool then! I've [read about this before](http://nuclexframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PrimitiveBatch&referringTitle=Nuclex.Graphics), maybe I'll look into it sometime. :-)

Comment: Yup! That Nuclex Framework looks quite interesting, I tried to do a similar thing (group batching) and found that building up the list of Vertices and Indices was much slower, so gave up on that idea. Feel free to ask for my source for my primitive drawing whenever. :)

Comment: WEll, just out of curiosity, try changing your SpriteBatch to SpriteSortMode.Texture and let me know if runs any faster than before.

Comment: It literally runs twice as slow... Weird...

Comment: I see. I think that just means that your "bottleneck" isn't the amount of texture changes on the graphics device, so all the sorting done by SpriteSortMode.Texture goes to waste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm almost sure this is because you're using `TextureAddressMode.Mirror` instead of `TextureAddressMode.Wrap`.

Change the value in the sampler state *before* rendering the primitives. I think it should be something like:

```cs
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0].AddressU = TextureAddressMode.Wrap;
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0].AddressV = TextureAddressMode.Wrap;
```

Comment: It is already .Wrap by default, and changing it to Mirror or Clamp does not work either.. ?

Comment: Are you sure it's not being changed to Mirror somewhere between *that* point and when the primitives are finally drawn? Do a `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0].AddressU);` right before the line that actually draws the primitives.

Comment: Ahh derp.. Found the problem... I was setting the UV Address mode WITHIN the Shader..

`sampler TextureSampler = sampler_state { texture = <xTexture>; magfilter = LINEAR; minfilter = LINEAR; mipfilter = NONE; AddressU = wrap; AddressV = wrap;};`

fixed it..

Comment: Glad you found it. That was going to be my next suggestion, because I wasn't sure if you were already using a shader or not.